# Retweet via Twitter API fails in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, twitter

I am using the [Tweetr](http://wiki.swfjunkie.com/tweetr) AS3 library in Flash.

Authentication, timeline retrieval and posting to Twitter all work fine.

For some reason the Retweet function works only a small part of the time and fails most of the times - I get a `Stream Error #2032` . When checking in Firebug I see that the call is made `(https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/[STATUSID].xml)` but it returns a`404` error. I can't see any difference between the times that it works and the times it doesn't.

Are there any known issues with Twitter's Retweet API that may cause this problem? Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

1. it would be nice to post some code,
2. are you sure you did not exceeded the calls/minute to twitter api,
3. if you put the same url in browser do you get something else or the same error ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome this problem by changing the URL to the Twitter API from https:// to http://. 
Still not sure why this problem was happening, but for the time being this will do the job for me.
Thanks.